# Function printing list of words

Tags: arrays, c, string, function, pointers

I'm trying to understand what is wrong here.

```
void longestConsec(char* strarr[], int n) {
  for(int i=0; i<n; i++)
  {
    printf("%s\n",strarr[i]);
  }
}

int main()
{
    char string[8][14] = {"zone", "abigail", "theta", "form", "libe", "zas", "theta", "abigail"};
    longestConsec(string, 8);
    return 0;
}
```

I want to print every single word, and for some reason it doesn't work. What I think of is that `strarr` is array of pointer to char, so in every cell there should be a word, right? But when i tried to debug the code i saw that strarr and strarr[0] have different memory locations. Why?

Comment: __"It doesn't work"__. Could you explain what output you see and unless obvious, why that output is wrong?

Comment: How did you see that `strarr` and `strarr[0]` have different memory locations?

Comment: Read your compiler warnings. They are there to help you.

Comment: Also, you might have a look here https://stackoverflow.com/q/1641957/6699433 because arrays and pointers are different things

Comment: @MikeCAT, I used watches window from debugger and I saw that they have different addresses.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

`strarr` is an array of pointers to char, but `string` is not an array of pointers but an array of 14-element array of chars.

Pointers and 14-element array of chars may have different size, so your code won't work well.

How about using array of pointers like this?

```
#include <stdio.h>

void longestConsec(const char* strarr[], int n) {
  for(int i=0; i<n; i++)
  {
    printf("%s\n",strarr[i]);
  }
}

int main()
{
    const char* string[8] = {"zone", "abigail", "theta", "form", "libe", "zas", "theta", "abigail"};
    longestConsec(string, 8);
    return 0;
}
```

Comment: `strarr` is NOT an array of pointers to char. It is a pointer to pointer to char.

Answer (score 1):

Your compiler should have given you a warning that gives a good hint.

```
k.c:12:19: warning: passing argument 1 of ‘longestConsec’ from incompatible pointer type [-Wincompatible-pointer-types]
   12 |     longestConsec(string, 8);
      |                   ^~~~~~
      |                   |
      |                   char (*)[14]
k.c:2:26: note: expected ‘char **’ but argument is of type ‘char (*)[14]’
    2 | void longestConsec(char* strarr[], int n) {
      |                    ~~~~~~^~~~~~~~
```

`string` is an array of arrays, `char[8][14]` and `strarr` is a pointer to pointer to char, `char **`. When `string` is passed to the function it decays to pointer to array of 14 char, `char (*)[14]`. Passing multidimensional arrays to functions can be tricky, but this works:

```
// size_t is better than int in this case
void longestConsec(size_t len, char strarr[][len], size_t n) 
{
    for(int i=0; i<n; i++)
        printf("%s\n",strarr[i]);
}
```

And then call it with:

```
longestConsec(sizeof string[0]/sizeof string[0][0], // 14
              string, 
              sizeof string/sizeof string[0]        // 8
              );
```

Note that you can write `sizeof string[0]` instead of `sizeof string[0]/sizeof string[0][0]` but that's because `sizeof char` is always 1.

Understanding these declarations can be a bit tricky. Just to give a type example of how they are declared:

```
char (*arr)[10]; // arr is a pointer to array of char of size 10
char *arr[10];   // arr is an array of 10 pointers to char
```

Related: [arrays are not pointers and pointers are not arrays](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/1641957/is-an-array-name-a-pointer)

Comment: Oh ok, thank you. I'll check the link. Now I understand these warnings. Didn't really think they are so useful.

Comment: @MihalacheRares Warnings are EXTREMLY useful. They explain a majority of bugs.